# Monitor directory for files and issue wget command?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, wget

I have an wget command running, but due to the website it regularly downloads "fake data". So, I am now downloading it dozens of times to get the correct content.

I now want the following:

```
use the wget command
check if in that directory are files <100kB
if yes ->use robocopy to save the >100kB files to another folder; repeat with wget 
if no -> stop
```

I have the wget command and the robocopy command.

I only need now the function to check if an directory has a file <100kB and how to put this together into an cmd/powershell/bat or whatever.

How would the command for that look like? I have especially no idea how to check the files.

Comment: The `FOR` command can be used to list files in a directory.  It also has an option to list the file size.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` to read the help for the `FOR` command.

Comment: Where is that file size stuff supposed to be?

Comment: Very last section of the help file for the `FOR` command. **In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:**  Then a few lines down it says. **%~zI        - expands %I to size of file**

Comment: Let's back up the bus.  I just realized your logic is incorrect. You logic says if there are files in the directory that are < 100 KB, then use Robocopy to copy the files > 100kb.  That will never be true.